# Is there a way to write a one column pd data frame on top of a mxn pd dataframe to a text file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have two data frames of different dimensions that I want to write to a text (.txt) file such that one is on top of the other. I'm sure it's easy but I have no way of doing it.
The data I want to write is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

preamble = pd.DataFrame(np.array(["software", "version", "frequency: 100", "firmware:100.10.1"]).T)

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"frame": np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), "X": np.array([2,4,6,8,10]), "Y": np.array([3,6,9,12,15]), "Z": np.array([1,2,3,4,5])})
```

I want to create a text file that looks like this:

```
software
version
frequency:100
firmware: 100.10.1
frame    X     Y    Z
1        2     3    1
2        4     6    2
3        6     8    3
4        8     10   4
5        10    12   5
```

I tried to get the format correctly at the top end.

I want to keep the [frame, X, Y, Z] headers where they are. But place the "preamble" at the top in a column.

I've tried to append and combine the two data frames, but can't do it. I don't think that's possible.

I've tried looking for ways to write the preamble in cell (column = 1, row = 1) and then start the data in cell (column = 1, row = 5).

Any help here would be appreciated! Please let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to use [to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html?highlight=to_string#pandas.DataFrame.to_string).

Here is a idea how to do this in your example:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(preamble.to_string(index=False).replace('0', '').replace(' ', '')[1:])
    fp.write('\n')
    fp.write(data.to_string())
```

Here I removed some element from the first string and did not use the index. I also added one newline character `\n` to seperate those two DataFrames.